# The reason for using react2angular package

Tags: angular, reactjs

I was learning React and came across package called react2angular. Initially I thought it is a package allowing to convert angular components to react and vice versa. But it turned out that it only allows to convert react components to angular. The question is "Is it primarily used when we developed our project with AngularJS but then decide to move to React? if so, what is the reason for converting react component to angular since cant't we keep creating components in angular rather than converting components from react." Or does it mean that we totally focus on React and just maintain our legacy AngularJS project by converting react components to angularjs?

Comment: It can be used if you have a react component library that you want to use in an AngularJS app or it can be used to facilitate a slow migration. It’s just to use react components in angular for whatever reason you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question,

> Is it primarily used when we developed our project with AngularJS but
>   then decide to move to React?

Yes, since AngularJS is deprecated, it becomes difficult for the developers to provide new features to an existing application. So many times, they convert the project to a newer tech-stack.

Now, completely revamping the project is a difficult and time-consuming task, so in such cases **react2angular** like libraries come in handy.

[Link](https://medium.com/@menidhikjha/react2angular-combining-angular-with-react-3606a5ed6828) to an article where this library was used to convert their project from AngularJS to React.